# Prove sequence inequality using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $${a_n} = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{1}{j}}  - \log n$$.
>   Prove:$$\frac{1}{{n + 1}} - \frac{1}{n} < {a_{n + 1}} - {a_n} < 0$$

I was guided to use Lagrange's MVT. 
At first, It looked a little weird because a sequence is discrete structure, while functions are infinitesimal.

But I did defined the function

$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^x {\frac{1}{j}} - \log (x)$$

From MVT:

$$f'(c) = \frac{1}{{x + 1}} - \log (x + 1) + \log (x)$$
where $$x < c < x+1$$.

Is that what am I supposed to do? How should I continue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about MVT, but you certainly have

$$a_{n+1}-a_n={1\over n+1}-\left(\log(n+1)-\log n\right)={1\over n+1}-\int_n^{n+1}{dx\over x}$$

You can put this together with ${1\over n+1}\lt{1\over x}\lt{1\over n}$ for $x$ on the interval $(n,n+1)$, which gives

$${1\over n+1}\lt \int_n^{n+1}{dx\over x}\lt {1\over n}$$

to get the two inequalities you want.

**Added in response to OP's comments**:  Dropping the integrals from what I wrote above, we have

$$a_{n+1}-a_n={1\over n+1}-\left(\log(n+1)-\log n\right)$$

so all we need show is

$${1\over n+1}\lt \log(n+1)-\log n \lt {1\over n}$$

Apply MVT, ${f(b)-f(a)\over b-a}=f'(c)$ for some $c\in(a,b)$, to the function $f(x)=\log x$ with $a=n$ and $b=n+1$:

$$\log(n+1)-\log n={\log(n+1)-\log n\over(n+1)-n}=f'(c)={1\over c}$$

The inequalities now follow from $n\lt c\lt n+1$.

Comment: It's a part of Calculus 1's exercise so we're not familiar with integrals yet.

Comment: In that case, what's your definition of the logarithm?

Comment: No definition given, therefore, it doesn't matter for the proof.

Comment: Wonderful. thanks mate!